# Search Center Crawl page  issue

Tags: 2007, windows-server, search

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 on Windows Server 2008. I am using Search Center to crawl web data source (i.e. crawl web page from other web sites). My question is related to incremental crawled page settings.

My question is if I have set to incremental crawl daily, what means crawl incremental? If Url itself does not change, but the Url's content is updated, if I set crawl to be incremental crawling, will it be re-crawled and store the lastest content of the Url?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be very close to your other question.  The index defines a resource (Page, document, list item, etc) and then continues to update the information about it.  In the case of a non-SharePoint site as in your other question, it will see a home page and all of the links to it.  It might crawl it 100 times in the course of crawling the website, but the home page will only be in there one time, and when you do a search you should only see it come up once.

The incremental crawls work the same way; adding new items and updating information about existing items.

Comment: Thanks Mike! The other question is dealing more with counters and this one is dealing more with the function of incremental crawl.

For your comments "adding new items and updating information about existing items" -- it means new Urls under this site will be crawled, Urls whose html content changed will also be clawled to reflect the lastest information about the Url?

Comment: My confusion is how SharePoint knows whether an existing Url changes or not?

Comment: Any updates to my question above? Thank you!